# php - Database driven PHP navigation

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have the following mysql table named **`pages`** :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id | menu_id | menu_text   | page_title  |  page_text             
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 1       | Home        | Homepage    |  Here is the page text 
 2  | 2       | About Us    | About Us    |  "      "      "     " 
 3  | 3       | History     | Our History |  "      "      "     " 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How would I make this possible to display as a menu?

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="http://localhost/index.php?id=1">Home</a></li> 
 <li>Over</li> 
  <ul> 
   <li><a href="http://localhost/speciaal.php">Wie zijn wij</a></li> 
   <li><a href="http://localhost/index.php?id=12">Geschiedenis</a></li> 
  </ul> 
 <li><a href="http://localhost/afbeeldingen.php">Afbeeldingen</a></li> 
 <li><a href="http://localhost/index.php?id=56">Contact</a></li> 
</ul>
```

I am desperated as I tried to make a code all night long and now I am clueless about how I could accomplish this system. As you can see is the page system in the menu above but I olso want to direct some menu links to other files on my webserver. I will be really thankful if somebody could post a sample code or put me in a easy direction accomplish my goal.

I do not know mutch yet about php.

Comment: Your sample data could not produce your sample menu. For starters your pages table should have a `urls` field so you can specify where the menu option should link to. Plus some way to indicate a hierarchy so you can tell what records are 'children' of other records.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I could add a `parent_ID` in my `pages` database table. Then do a simple fetch_assoc and ORDER them ASC by `parent_ID` to put them in a while to do the <li> but now I am clueless how to make submenu's like the sample I posted above in my first post with other URLS in it that don't come from the `pages` table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/317/formatting-a-multi-level-menu-using-only-one-query.html

Comment: I saw this page before and I am going to try and follow this one more time. I have one question about that article: How could I manage to put the pages from my `pages` table within that code so it would generate a menu. It doesn't make sence to me.